# Using Android Emulator with an Apple Magic Mouse

Tags: android-studio, magic-mouse

I am testing an Android App using Android Studio under macOS.

I find that using a magic mouse, sometimes I get a touch event when moving the mouse over the emulated screen, even though I have not clicked the mouse.

Anyone else experience this?

Comment: Yes, I.m too. So weird behaviour of Magic Mouse